# window.location.href running in indefinite loop despite return false statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm on page `2.html` and I click on `.next` button it goes into infinite loop instead of navigating to page `3.html`.

```
/* Init current page */
var current_page = localStorage.getItem("current_page");

/* If current page is undefined set set it to first page */
if (current_page === null) {
    current_page = 1;
    localStorage.setItem("current_page", current_page); 
}

/* Load first page or where user had left off */
if (current_page != 1){
    window.location.href = current_page + ".html";
    return false
}


/* Navigate to next page */
$('button.next').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    current_page = parseInt(current_page)+1;
    localStorage.setItem("current_page", current_page);
    location.reload();
});
```

I've defined window.location.href during page load because the user should be taken to the last visited page incase if they drop off and return back.

Comment: not sure what you would expect `return false` to do in this case. It will never execute anyway since page will reload before that line. What exactly are you trying to do? Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation of what you expect the code to do

Comment: @charlietfl When user clicks on `.next` button it should navigate user to the next page but instead it's running in indefinite loop.

Comment: If `current_page` e.g equals 2, then your code would call `window.location.href = current_page + ".html";` on each reload. It doesn't make sense because btw `window.location.href` will reload the page

Comment: So that is done in the button click handler ...  your problem exists in the code before that....and the code before the button click doesn't make sense and you didn't tell us what you expect it to do

Comment: @charlietfl I've defined window.location.href during page load because the user should be taken to the last page incase if they drop off and return back.

Comment: Then explain the expected behavior in the question...you completely missed doing that. Also don't compare it to `1` since that condition will only be true on page one. That's why it loops on other pages

Comment: You will need to parse the url to get page number, or set a variable in script in each page identifying the page number

Comment: I've updated my answer since after @RahulDagli updated the question is more clear, take a look

Answer (score 0):

On each page set a variable `activePage` that matches your filename number and compare to that instead of always comparing to `1` before doing redirect

```
var activePage = 3;

if (current_page != activePage ){
    window.location.href = current_page + ".html";       
}
```

Alternatively you can parse the url to get the active page number from file name